# PSD from time series with python

Tags: python, time-series

i have a time series and i want to make the periodogram and the PSD to extract additional information. The data is two column one date(YYYY/mm/dd) and the other is displacement in meters.I have 8 years of data and one point per date.Any suggestion?

Comment: What have you tried? Did you estimate the amount of the data at hand, do you have an idea of applicable algorithms? What does "PSD" mean, by the way?

Comment: First of all PSD(Power Spectrum Density) of course i have tried with python doing an FFT with scipy importing tha data to a table.  `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
import numpy as np  data = np.genfromtxt('Mydata',dtype=None, delimiter='  ',usecols=(1))  spectrum = np.fft.fft(data)  freq = np.fft.fftfreq(len(spectrum))  plt.plot(freq, abs(spectrum))  plt.show()`  so i want to do the opposite from this question at stack overflow [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29095386/compute-time-series-from-psd-python]

Comment: 8 years of data, 1 measurement a day is 365.25 * 8 = 2922 data points; nothing much. I suppose you can sort and parse your data, so that you have a list of pairs `(timestamp, displacement)` sorted by timestamp. If any days are missing, I'd interpolate at this step, because FFT needs uniform input. Then you'd likely do FFT on just the list of `displacement`s. Your frequency domain is "1/day", not "1/s", but otherwise these data are no different. What problem am I missing?

Comment: After I am doing this I get a large amplitude at 0 that's because I am having a DC component into my time series i have to subtract from each value the mean to get a reasonable result also how can I get the vertical results at Db?